# Как написать чужому Telegram боту используя Python?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Нужно провзаимодействовать с чужим Telegram ботом (написать сообщение, получить сообщение), используя скрипт на  Python.

Обычный бот такого, конечно, не сможет.

С помощью какой технологии (библиотеки) можно решить такую задачу?

Comment: Использовать api телеграм-клиента и писать с аккаунта человека.

Comment: @Qwertie спасибо